# SSH connects but stays on the same machine

Tags: ssh, networking, virtual-machine, kvm, hostname

I've got an unusual problem at hand that I couldn't solve for 2 days.

I've got two KVM running on my real machine. One of them is named `headnode` and the second is named `computenode`. These machines run CentOS 7 and my real machine runs Ubuntu 16.

I set up `/etc/hosts` files to contain their IPs along with their hostnames. It looks like this for `headnode`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.1.1   headnode
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.192.122.101 computenode
10.42.0.45 MyMachine
```

The problem is that I cannot SSH from `headnode` to `computenode`. It usually goes like this:

```
[root@headnode ~]# ssh root@computenode
root@computenode's password: 
Last login: Fri Aug  3 11:24:01 2018 from gateway
[root@headnode ~]#
```

Do you see the problem? It stayed on `headnode`. The first thing that comes to mind is that I configured `/etc/hosts` wrong, but it is not the case. I check more than 20 times, perhaps much more. I retyped the whole file many times. It doesn't fix it.

I can ping the computenode from headnode normally.

```
[root@headnode ~]# ping -c 3 computenode
PING computenode (127.192.122.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from computenode (127.192.122.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
64 bytes from computenode (127.192.122.101): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from computenode (127.192.122.101): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms

--- computenode ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.096/0.104/0.108/0.005 ms
```

As you can see, it pings the correct IP.

When I use `-v` option of SSH, it also proves that it looks like it is connecting to the correct IP:

```
debug1: Connecting to computenode [127.192.122.101] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

There is nothing unusual in the debugs I could see.

However, when you watch the `audit.log` file of the `computenode`, it receives no connection attempt whatsoever! It eliminates the possibility of `computenode` rejecting the connection or tunnelling it.

There is no problem connecting from `computenode` to `headnode` through SSH, or connecting to `MyMachine` from either of them.

These are fresh machines, I only configured `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/sysconfig/network` to add it only HOSTNAME variable and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to change the IP.

The problem summary is that I think `headnode` resolves `computenode` to correct IP, but then connects back to itself and doesn't send anything to `computenode` whatsoever.

Moreover, I removed everything KVM and their images and setup new ones. It happened again! I added a third machine, it didn't happen with that one.

I disabled the NetworkManager and stopped it, I disabled the firewall.

I **can** SSH from headnode to computenode by using computenode's IP directly:

```
ssh root@192.168.122.101
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you ssh directly to the IP? `ssh root@127.192.122.101`

Comment: Nothing in all you wrote proves that you actually ping or connect to the computernode. By default all of 127.0.0.0/8 belongs to the local host, thus including 127.192.122.101. You'd have to show what network settings or proxy etc. would allow to change the default behaviour

Comment: @KevinLemaire Sorry! I forgot to add one of the most important things there. I can connect like that without problem.

Comment: @A.B Oh my! Even though I checked probably 80 times, I did not notice I mistyped the IP in the hosts. Sometimes you just go blind I guess. It is also interesting that I made the same mistake many times over and over again in every KVM. It is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that I typed the IP in the /etc/hosts wrong over and over again. Absurdly, I made the same mistake every time I set up KVMs and I did not notice it no matter how many times I checked it.

If you have a similar problem, read every character in the /etc/hosts file and ask your colleagues to read them as well. Sometimes, you just can't see.